# Error while executing make command to create moses\scripts\training\memscore

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

I have to implement the machine translation system hence I am planning use moses but I facing following error while executing make command on Cygwin:

```
Administrator@diebold-69b7050 /cygdrive/c/JT/NewSetup/Moses/moses-2010-08-13/moses/scripts/training/memscore$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/JT/NewSetup/Moses/moses-2010-08-13/moses
scripts/training/memscore'
g++ -I/usr/include -Wall -ffast-math -ftrapping-math -fomit-frame-pointer -g -O2    -o memscore.exe  phrasetable.o memscore.o  scorer.o lexdecom.o      -lz -lm
phrasetable.o: In function `_ZlsRSoRK15PhraseAlignment':
/cygdrive/c/JT/NewSetup/Moses/moses-2010-08-13/moses/scripts/training/memscore/phrasetable.cpp:111: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
phrasetable.o: In function `__tcf_0':
/cygdrive/c/JT/NewSetup/Moses/moses-2010-08-13/moses/scripts/training/memscore/datastorage.h:31: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
phrasetable.o: In function `_ZN14PhrasePairInfo12realloc_dataEj':
/usr/include/boost/pool/simple_segregated_storage.hpp:97: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
phrasetable.o: In function `_ZNK14PhrasePairInfo14get_alignmentsEv':
```

Please don't give me suggestion like linker error because I am completely fad up of trying linker option.

I think, I have some Cygwin->Boot library problem. Can you suggest me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are mssing `-lboost_system` on your compilation commands.

Some of the boost libraries are header only. Others need to be compiled. And the libraries sometimes depend on each other. In this case you are using some boost library which needs `-lboost_system`.  Add it so that it gets linked with your project.

and it should be on this line. Where linking is done

```
g++ -I/usr/include -Wall -ffast-math -ftrapping-math -fomit-frame-pointer -g -O2 -o memscore.exe  phrasetable.o memscore.o  scorer.o lexdecom.o  **-lboost_system** -lz -lm
```

Comment: I have already tried this option while compilation but its gives the warning "g++: -lboost_system: linker input file unused because linking not done" and after that its gives above mentioned error.

Comment: Still problem not solved even I tried sample boot program on cygwin and its run successfully but my problem is not solved on same terminal. Please help me.

Comment: You also have to make sure that boost_system exists on the system, and you have added the folder where `boost_system` is located is included in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.or you have to tell the compiler like `-L"where/boost/system/is"`

Comment: Boost system is installed on my machine and sample program also run on same successfully. Its present on "C:\cygwin\lib". For testing purpose I have rename the boost_system.lib.o from boost_system.lib and then program given error "i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system". It mean cygwin accessing boost_system.lib on same path. Still how i can tell compiler where boot system installed? Or Which else libraries accessing by boost_system internally? Or How can I find it?

Comment: Firstly I thanks to you. Finally I have the solved problem by copying all lib files while having .a extension to bin folder.